# SQLite find the differences between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have two tables that both contain `id(primary key)`, `contact_id` and `name`. 
I want to find out the differences between two tables. So, if one record in `table A` is different than `table B`, the sql query should find it. For example, in the code below, `('2','test2')` does not appear in table B. So, the record `('2','test2')` is difference between two tables. However, we might have opposite situations such as one record appears in `table B` but not `table A`. Or a record's `contact_id` could be the same in both table, but the `name` field can be different. In this case, the different record should also be returned. I have done this, but it does not seem to work for all cases. How to get it work for all cases?

```
CREATE TABLE A 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     contact_id int(20),
      name varchar(20)
    );

CREATE TABLE B 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     contact_id int(20),
      name varchar(20)
    );

INSERT INTO A
(contact_id,name)
VALUES
('1','test1'),
('2','test2');

INSERT INTO B
(contact_id,name)
VALUES
('1','test1');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM A
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM B
UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM B
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM A
```

Here is the sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f7f45/9
and select cancel in the pop-up screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

left join a to b where b is null to get whats in a but not b, left join b to a where a is null to get whats in b and not a.

```
select 'in a but not b', a.* 
from a left join b on a.contact_id = b.contact_ID
where b.contact_ID is null
union all
select'in b but not a', b.* 
from b left join a on a.contact_id = b.contact_ID
where a.contact_ID is null
```

I put a field in to denote where the record originates from since it won't be obvious in the union results.  If you were interested, a third query to check where the record is in both a and b by ID however have different values for name...same idea, just inner join:

```
select a.*,b.*
from a inner join b on a.contact_id = b.contact_ID
where a.name <> b.name
```

Comment: heh, unfortunately no...sql.js isn't supported in this backwards IE version I'm forced to use here.  You should be able to past the code here in your fiddle to confirm it works.

Comment: any error returned?  syntax looks right to me, but I don't have sqlite to test it fully.  does select 'in a but not b', a.* 
from a left join b on a.contact_id = b.contact_ID
where b.contact_ID is null --
 work when ran on it's own?

Comment: What error are you receiving? @Twelfth's code works in my testing.

Comment: @Ilion, I am not getting any error but the result is empty. maybe you can upload a sqlfiddle link and i will see the correct result.

Comment: @llion thanks!   It works on mysql and mssql for me atleast, can't prove this sqlite though

Comment: How to involve name field?

Comment: it's part of table a and b...a.* or b.* should 'involve' it.  If thats not what you want, pls define what you mean by involving it (give it a cookie?)

Comment: Is there any way to select the difference between table a in sqlite db file A and table b in sqlite db file B?

Answer (score 5):

EXCEPT does not bind stronger than UNION ALL (and indenting the query does not change this), so the database will execute the UNION ALL before the second EXCEPT.

You have to move the two EXCEPT queries into subqueries to ensure that the UNION ALL is executed last:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A
               EXCEPT
               SELECT * FROM B)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM B
               EXCEPT
               SELECT * FROM A)
```